# Why bash consider every character as a number

Tags: bash, shell

This is the code:

```
sum=0
i=1

while [ $i -le $# ]
do
if [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
then
        sum=$(($sum+$(eval echo '$'$(eval echo ${i}))))
        echo "$(eval echo '$'$(eval echo $i)) is number"
        i=$((i+1))
else
        echo "$(eval echo '$'$(eval echo $i)) is not a number"
        i=$((i+1))
fi
done
echo "sum is $sum"
```

and this is the output when I try to distinguish b/w numbers and characters:

```
$ bash sumOfGivenNums.sh 3 4 3 a
3 is number
4 is number
3 is number
a is number
sum is 10
```

Comment: You're never looking at the value of the `i`-th argument. You're just looking at the value of `i`, which is always a number (you start with `i=1` and increment it).

Comment: Use `${!i}`  to get the value of the i'th argument

Comment: There are easier ways to iterate over the arguments to your script. Consider, e.g., `for arg in "$@"; do ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a lot of really unnecessary code in your script; you almost never want to use the `eval` function. I would probably write something like this:

```
sum=0

for arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ $arg =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$arg is a number"
    (( sum += arg ))
  else
    echo "$arg is not a number."
  fi
done

echo "sum is $sum"
```

Comment: I'd also suggest `sum=$(( sum + arg ))`, `let` being an [obsolete](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) compatibility facility intended to support scripts written for pre-POSIX shells -- or, if we want to use bashisms, `(( sum += arg ))`.